# Find the volume inside both $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=1$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

What is the volume inside both $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=1$?

The chapter I am working on is called Change of Variables in Multiple Integrals, for my Vector Calculus class.

I understand that we will be taking the double integral of these two shapes to find the volume between both of them, but I am very lost as to how to begin. Should I convert to polar coordinates or should I replace one equation into the other, IE $x^2+y^2=u$ and I could place that into the first equation, then replace it with 1 since $x^2+y^2=u=1$. Or should I set them equal to each other and try to find the bounds like that?

I'd appreciate any input, I am just very confused as to how to approach the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solid is the intersection of a sphere of radius 4 with a cylinder of radius 1. If you look down on the solid from the positive $z$ direction you will see the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ in the $xy$ plane. Since the solid is bounded on the top and bottom by the sphere you can set up the integral as
$$
V = \iint_D [\text{top_edge} - \text{bottom_edge}] \, \mathrm dA
$$ 
where $D$ is the unit disk $\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$. Thus your volume integral is
$$
V = \iint_D 2 \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2} \, \mathrm dx \mathrm dy.
$$
I would use polar coordinates to evaluate.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Just one question: in the final formula why is there a 2 before the square root sign?

Comment: Because $z$ is from $ -\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} $ to $ \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} $.

Comment: The bottom surface is $z = - \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$.

Comment: The sphere is radius $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change coordinates. Let $r^2=x^2+y^2$. Then we are worried about the volume of the cylinder $r^2<=1$ insde the sphere $r^2+z^2\le4$

So the integral is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}1 dzrdrd\theta=\int_0^1 (-2\pi)(-2r) \sqrt{4-r^2}dr=(-2\pi)\frac{2}{3}(4-r^2)^\frac{3}{2}|_0^1=32\pi/3-4\pi\sqrt{3}$.